# In Angular, given an array of objects and a single input, how do bind the input so that it represents a given property of all the objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given an array of objects (such as would represent a selection of items, for example), and an input, how do you go about binding the input value so that it represents a given property of all the objects?

The input should display state in the manner:

- if all values for this property are the same on all objects, display that value
- if at least one value is not the same, set the input.value to 'multiple'
- if all values are undefined, set the input.value to 'none'

I have the function that aggregates the values for a given property exposed on the scope:

```
// Return value (if all values are equal) or undefined (if not)
scope.getSelection('property')
```

I also have the function that sets a value on all the objects:

```
scope.setSelection('property', value)
```

I can't find a combination ng-value, ng-model and ng-change that allows me to both get from .getSelection() and set to .setSelection() automatically, so I'm assuming I have to write a new directive.

What's the idiomatic way to solve this problem?

Comment: do you plan to select a property from a select then checkCondition and return a result? do you have one input or input per property?

Comment: If your application will run only on fairly modern browsers, maybe getters/setters will help you: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Comment: @wickY26 If you mean a <select>, then no, I am not using a select. I have one input per property.

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos Perhaps. i don't think that changes much. I still have to make a controller for each input in order to declare a new scope with the getter / setter on it, and even then the set will have to take place inside a $scope.$apply or angular won't know to propagate updates...

Comment: I am not sure I understand your concept correctly. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/52HE6/) what you want?

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos Oooo. Thank you for writing that. That is a way forwards. It does mean I need to know the property names in order to declare them in the controller, but that's not a biggie.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/52HE6/1/) out for a slightly different optical result. As for the reusability, yes you are right. But this is only a proof-of-concept, I trust you can find ways to make this generic :)

Comment: Yes, I did already consider using the [placeholder]. I argued to myself that it wasn't semantic in the end :) I may use a class to change the optical result.

Comment: If you want to put your solution in an answer, I'll happily mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of future reference, let me write a full answer:

A way to accomplish this in fairly modern browsers is using property getters/setters ([spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)). An example, proof-of-concept implementation would be:

Let's say the `$scope` contains the following collection:

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 1, prop: "a"},
    {id: 2, prop: "a"},
    {id: 3, prop: "a"}
];
```

And we want to manipulate the aggregate of the `item.prop` property. We define another object as:

```
$scope.form = {
    get aggregate() {
        var res, i;
        for( i=0; i < $scope.items.length; i++ ) {
            if( typeof(res) === "undefined" ) {
                res = $scope.items[i].prop;
            }
            else if( $scope.items[i].prop !== res ) {
                return "(multiple)";
            }
        }
        return res;
    },
    set aggregate(val) {
        var i;
        for( i=0; i < $scope.items.length; i++ ) {
            $scope.items[i].prop = val;
        }
    }
};
```

The `form.aggregate` property now has a getter and setter. These function handle their values by iterating over `$scope.items`. The getter compares the values and returns the common one, if all are the same or `"(multiple)"` if at least one is different. The setter just sets the given value to all properties.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52HE6/

And an improved (IMO) version, using a placeholder instead of the literal `"(multiple)"`: http://jsfiddle.net/52HE6/1/

This pattern can probably be generalized/parameterized (i.e. no fixed name `prop`), e.g. as (WARNING: UNTESTED):

```
function aggregatorFactory($scope, collectionName, propName) {
    return {
        get aggregate() {
            var res, i;
            for( i=0; i < $scope[collectionName].length; i++ ) {
                if( typeof(res) === "undefined" ) {
                    res = $scope[collectionName][i][propName];
                }
                else if( $scope[collectionName][i][propName] !== res ) {
                    return "(multiple)";
                }
            }
            return res;
        },
        set aggregate(val) {
            var i;
            for( i=0; i < $scope[collectionName].length; i++ ) {
                $scope[collectionName][i][propName] = val;
            }
        }
    };
}
```